# Auctex font shortcut

Tags: fonts, auctex

In Aquamacs, I would like to create a keyboard shortcut for the following command:

```
{\Hiero }
```

for a text I want to select or type. 
I googled and I have not been able to find a working answer

Answer (score 5):

Add the following code to your init file.

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(setq TeX-font-list
     (append
      TeX-font-list
      '((?\C-h "{\\Hiero " "}")))))
```

In this way you can insert `{\Hiero }` at point or wrap it around the selected text with <kbd>C-C h</kbd> (but you can change the key binding in the code).

---

The previous code exploits AUCTeX font management, here is a different solution making only use of standard Emacs Lisp.

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map
     (kbd "C-C h")
     (lambda (&optional beg end)
       (interactive "r")
       (if (TeX-active-mark)
       (progn
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char end)
           (insert "}"))
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char beg)
           (insert "{\\Hiero ")))
     (insert "{\\Hiero ")
     (save-excursion
       (insert "}"))))))
```

Comment: it works perfectly. Where did you find the documentation about it? I thought of hacking the normal AucTeX commands like typewriter, but I did not know where they were anyway.@giordano

Comment: @RobertoGozzoli  I added another solution, using AUCTeX font management.  The original code uses standard Emacs Lisp, you can start taking a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html